# how to get google map marker left and right lat lng and distance

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

how to get left and right `lat` `lng` and distance from the google map marker point pls find the below image for reference. **Note**: from the marker point only i need to take left and right `lat` and `lng` distance should be around 100m, 100m is not also fixed it can be changed 10m or 50m in future. Is it possible to do that using google map API V3. [image]

Comment: If the distance isn't fixed, how are you planning inputting it?  Have you looked at the [geometry library's computeOffset method](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3.exp/geometry#spherical.computeOffset)?

Comment: @geocodezip thank you for your reply yes i am fixing it globally i can change it whatever i want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [computeOffset](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3.exp/geometry#spherical.computeOffset) method of the geometry library:

```
var markE = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(map.getCenter(), distance, 90),
  map: map,
  label: "E"
})
var markW = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(map.getCenter(), distance, -90),
  map: map,
  label: "W"
})
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/u7qjn9xj/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;
var distance = 100; // meters
function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {
      lat: 13.025228,
      lng: 80.257518
    },
    zoom: 18
  });
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: map.getCenter(),
    map: map
  });
  var markE = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(map.getCenter(), distance, 90),
    map: map,
    label: "E"
  })
  var markW = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(map.getCenter(), distance, -90),
    map: map,
    label: "W"
  })
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```